# how to default gnome-session-flashback as default desktop for future new users on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gdm, gnome-session-fallback

my users exist on ldap and when they log on a machine I want them using gnome-session-flashback

what I've tried so far and hasn't worked

copy to skel a user folder after I made sure that user has gnome-session-flashback chosen by default ( choose flashback, enter, reboot, it has flashback prechosen )

this https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-user.html.en

in ubuntu 16.04 I did this in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
user-session=gnome-flashback-metacity
I haven't found an equivalent in gnome/ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=gnome-flashback-metacity
```

Create new configuration file with above content and put it in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`. For more info you could read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM).

Comment: doing that is exactly what I described in my OP I did on ubuntu 16.04 with lightdm, my question is how to achieve the same with ubuntu's 18.04 gdm3

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that you want that with `gdm`... Don't know answer for that.

Answer (score -1):

I try it in myself and successful.

```
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo apt remove gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -> [lightdm]

~check path, gnome-flashback-metacity
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager

* 0            /usr/lib/gnome-flashback/gnome-flashback-metacity   60        auto
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-session                                                               50        manual
  2            /usr/lib/gnome-flashback/gnome-flashback-metacity   60        auto

~auto setting, up priority of gnome-flashback-metacity
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-session-manager x-session-manager /usr/lib/gnome-flashback/gnome-flashback-metacity 60
```

If you are using unicode as language, select language in "install stage" or system will strange.